# Deny access to a path (give 403 or 404 response)

Tags: redirect, htaccess, 404-error

I know this should be easy.  BBpress creates user profiles at /forums/users/.

I'd like to make them unavailable to anyone, and not be indexed by Google.  I've tried the following (in .htaccess) and more, but nothing seems to work.  Is it because these are not real directories, just a page hierarchy created by BBpress?  What's the solution?

```
# RedirectMatch 404 ^/fora/users/.*$

# RedirectMatch 404 ^.*/users/.*$

# this give internal server error throughout site:
# <Files ~ "/users/">
# Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
# </FilesMatch>

# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteRule ^.*/users/.*$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # this give internal server error throughout site:
> <Files ~ "/users/">
> Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
> </FilesMatch>
> ```

This would give an "internal server error" (500 response) because you've used `</FilesMatch>` to close the `<Files>` section. It should be `</Files>`.

But as you suggested, this won't work anyway, as the `<Files>` directive matches real files only, not virtual URL-paths.

But you don't need to set the `X-Robots-Tag` if you simply want to block (403 Forbidden) the request.

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteRule ^.*/users/.*$ - [F]
> ```

This should work, in order to send a "403 Forbidden" response for any URL that contains `/users/` as part of the URL-path, providing you place this at the *top* of your `.htaccess`, *before* the WordPress code block (ie. before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section).

However, you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive. And the `RewriteRule` *pattern* should be modified to avoid matching `/users/` *anywhere* in the URL-path, otherwise, it could potentially block valid URLs.

Try the following instead at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^forums/users/ - [F]
```

This blocks any request that simply starts `/forums/users/`.

Note there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

---

**UPDATE:** If this fails to work then make sure you don't have a custom 403 `ErrorDocument` defined. If not then this could still be configured in your server config (by your web host), which is out of your control. However, you can still reset this to the default Apache error response in your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 default
```

> a way to make it go 404 instead, ...? I don't find such a flag for RewriteRule.

You can use the `R=404` flag instead of `F` to trigger a "404 Not Found" response. Whilst this might look like a "redirect", since it's using the `R` (`redirect`) flag, it's not an external redirect (which is only triggered for 3xx response codes).

In fact, you can use `R=403` instead of `F` if you wanted to. `F` is simply a shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Still can't get it to work.  It's first in .htaccess.  With or without leading slash, using forums or fora (which I changed the permalink to in bbpress settings), and whether or not I append '.*$'    My page for example: https://forestpathology.org/fora/users/jim2/

Comment: And this directive is at the _top_ of your `.htaccess` file, before any other directives? The order of directives is important. Is this `.htaccess` file located in the document root of your site? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Yes, at the very top.  Here are other .htaccess files 
'./wp-content/cache/autoptimize/.htaccess
./wp-content/wflogs/.htaccess
./wp-content/plugins/akismet/.htaccess
./wp-content/plugins/wordfence/models/.htaccess
./wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/.htaccess
./wp-content/plugins/wordfence/waf/.htaccess
./wp-content/plugins/wordfence/modules/login-security/classes/.htaccess
./wp-content/plugins/wordfence/modules/login-security/views/.htaccess'

Comment: And ./wp-content/plugins/wordfence/views/.htaccess
./wp-content/plugins/wordfence/tmp/.htaccess
./wp-content/plugins/wordfence/vendor/.htaccess
./wp-content/uploads/sucuri/.htaccess'.      Yes, .htaccess is in the root, in the public_html folder

Comment: Hhhmm, that's strange. This "should" work from the information posted. From your URL structure, `^fora/users/` would seem to be the correct regex in the above `RewriteRule` (adding `.*$` would make no difference - that would work as well). To clarify, `/fora` is not a physical subdirectory? Do you have a custom 403 ErrorDocument? Do you know if your system is using mod_rewrite inheritance? Do you have access to the server config? Do you mind sharing your complete `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Correct, /fora is not a physical directory.  I also can't get that rewrite to work on other permalink paths, like `about/`.  No custom 403, although it seems at server level there is a 403->404 redirect of some kind.  I do have some php to modify the text in the 404, but no custom page.  We definitely have mod-rewrite, but I don't know about inheritance (or what it is).  Is there a way I can send you the `.htaccess`?  Thanks for sticking with me!  Oh, no access to server config.

Comment: More troubleshooting: I used the Health Check & Troubleshooting plugin to disable all plugins (except bbPress) and switch to default 2020 theme.  Still no redirect/error page - went to the user profile.

Comment: Do you have a custom 403 ErrorDocument defined? Either way, try setting `ErrorDocument 403 default` to reset the error document to the server default. (It's possible the "redirect" is being triggered in a custom `ErrorDocument` - which might even be defined in the server config.)

Comment: (Sorry, you already said you don't have a custom ErrorDocument defined. However, this could still be defined in the server config - that you don't have access to - so setting this to `default` is worth a try. Some shared hosts do "mess" with the custom error documents.)

Comment: `ErrorDocument 403 default` (placed before the rewrite block) did the trick.  You are a master sleuth, sir!  It now displays a 403 Forbidden page.  This is great, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make it go 404 instead, as I've read then you're not divulging whether the page exists?  I don't find such a flag for RewriteRule.

Comment: Glad it's now working. You can change the `F` flag to `R=404` instead to trigger a 404 response. Whilst this uses the `R` (`redirect`) flag, it's not an external redirect.

Comment: Well, the R=404 doesn't work (goes to the user profile page instead).  I'm guessing that's got something to do with the theme defining a 'custom' 404 page?  That's fine, I'll just leave it as F.  Thanks again.

Comment: "something to do with the theme defining a 'custom' 404 page?" - Ah yes, quite possibly!

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's a pretty permalink created with rewrite rules for your posts/pages/CPT's and not a real directory.

You can add the `nofollow` to a page that uses a certain php template (check [body class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/)) or to the archive page of your CPT (if `users` is a CPT) by adding this to your functions.php or in a (mu-)plugin:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
    if( is_page_template('single-users.php') || is_post_type_archive('users') ) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
    }
} );
```

Furthermore, you can add a `wp_redirect` to the top of each template and send to your 404 page, like this:

```
$url = get_template_part( 404 );
wp_redirect($url, 404);
```

Alternatively you can use the Wordpress function `status_header()` to add the `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` header

```
function 404_my_event() {
  global $post;
  if ( is_singular( 'event' ) && !rr_event_should_be_available( $post->ID ) ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', '404_my_event' );
```

References:

- [wp-head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/)
- [Conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/)
- [status_header](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/status_header/)

Comment: Thank you for all your work on that @GeorgeP.  I couldn't figure out what to substitute into the function.  The body has about a dozen classes:

Comment: OK, commenting here is a learning experience.  I was able to target the user profile pages in the function with 'if (bbp_is_single_user())'.  I have no idea about the archive.   Regarding the 404, I don't know what templates to edit with the first option.  I'll have to study the second option and see if I can figure out what's going on there and how to use it.